# Scriplet to include localSession variable

Tags: javascript, jsp, local-storage, scriptlet

I have 2 pages of JSP files, in the first JSP i have this lines included in my javascript function. how do I retrieve the *localstorage* item in my scriplet? Any help will be very much appreciated, thank you in advance.

```
localStorage.setItem("surveyDescription", surveyDescription);
window.location = 'Page2.jsp';
```

Answer (score 1):

### Scope of JSP Objects

The availability of a JSP object for use from a particular place of the application is defined as the scope of that JSP object. Every object created in a JSP page will have a scope. Object scope in JSP is segregated into **four parts** and they are page, request, session and application.

#### 1. page

- ‘page’ scope means, the JSP object can be accessed only from *within the same page where it was created*. The default scope for JSP objects created using `<jsp:useBean>` tag is page.
- [JSP implicit objects](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/java.817/a83726/genlovw3.htm#1007386) `out`, `exception`, `response`, `pageContext`, `config` and `page` have ‘page’ scope.

#### 2. request

- A JSP object created using the ‘request’ scope can be *accessed from any pages that serves that request*. More than one page can serve a single request. The JSP object will be bound to the request object. Implicit object request has the ‘request’ scope.

#### 3. session

- ‘session’ scope means, the JSP object is accessible from pages that *belong to the same session from where it was created*. The JSP object that is created using the session scope is bound to the session object. Implicit object session has the ‘session’ scope.

#### 4. application

- A JSP object created using the ‘application’ scope can be *accessed from any pages across the application*. The JSP object is bound to the application object. Implicit object application has the ‘application’ scope.

---

Read more from [Oracle Official Document - Object Scopes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/java.817/a83726/genlovw3.htm#1007387) that states:

There are four possible scopes:

1. `page` - The object is accessible only from within the JSP page where it was created. Note that when the user refreshes the page while executing a JSP page, new instances will be created of all page-scope objects.
2. `request` - The object is accessible from any JSP page servicing the same HTTP request that is serviced by the JSP page that created the object.
3. `session` - The object is accessible from any JSP page sharing the same HTTP session as the JSP page that created the object.
4. `application` - The object is accessible from any JSP page used in the same Web application (within any single Java virtual machine) as the JSP page that created the object.

   ---

Now choose any one based on your need. If you are talking about 2 JSP pages then choose `session` scope because request is not forwarded or included from one JSP to another.

Simply call `setAttribute(key,value)` method on [implicit object](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnaij/index.html) `page`,`request`,`session` and `application` to set an attribute in any scope and get the value back using `getAttribute(key)` from the same scope.

**Note:** Always try to avoid *Scriplet* instead use [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html) and [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html).

Comment: thank you for your reply Braj! will look into the document link, thanks again